# how to convert backslash to forward slash in path name on gcp using python

Tags: file, google-cloud-platform, local, copying

while copying the file path from local to Google Cloud Platform, the path at local is in `retail_db\categories\part-00000` format whereas GCP is accepting format as `retail_db/categories/part-00000`

I have successfully copied the path to GCP but it is showing like this:
`gs://kiretail/pythondemo/retail_db\categories\part-00000`

How to replace this backward slash with forward slash?

tried using this:

```py
path.replace("\\", "/")
```

But still I am missing something.
Below is the code to copy filepath to gcp:

```
files = filter(lambda item: os.path.isfile(item), items)
bucket = gsclient.get_bucket('kiretail')
for file in files:
print(f'Uploading file {file}')
blob_suffix = '/'.join(file.split('/')[3:])
blob_name = f'{tgt_base_dir}/{blob_suffix}'

blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
blob.upload_from_filename(file)
```

Below is the code I tried:

```
for x in blobs:
 replace("\\", "/")
```

Comment: The method `path.replace()` will work. What problem do you have using it? Show your code so that we do not have to guess what you are doing.

Comment: Hii John, I have added two code snippets in the above post. Please check

Comment: Post code, not images of code.

Comment: @Kirtim please never posts pictures of code here, please [edit] your question and paste code and use the Textbox Tools to Code Format the codes. Posting pictures of code means no one can copy paste or search for it and it attracts downvotes.

Comment: As per your suggestion I have edited the post with code.

Comment: 1) Code indentation is critical for Python. Correct your code 2) Do not say I tried this code out of context. Show the code with `path.replace()` e.g. show a complete example.

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 for x in blobs:
      2  path.replace("\\", "/")

NameError: name 'blobs' is not defined